# Proof that $\rho = \pm1$ implies linear combination

Tags: statistics, correlation

I need to prove that
$$\rho(X,Y) = \pm 1 \implies Y = aX+b,$$
for some constants $a, b$.

With the help of [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/821409/coefficent-of-correlation-smaaller-than-1-proof-problem) and [this document](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~ecroot/3225/rho_notes.pdf) here's what I've got so far:

Let $X, Y$ be random variables and $a$ some constant. $aX + Y$ is also a random variable whose variance by definition is non-negative
$$V(aX+Y) \ge 0.$$
From variance properties:
$$a^2 V(X)+2a\text{Cov}{X,Y}+V(Y)\ge 0$$
This is a quadratic as a function of $a$, which has a maximum of 1 root. It has a root only for $a$ that satisfies $$a^2 V(X)+2a\text{Cov}{X,Y}+V(Y)=0$$
let it be $a_0$. That means that
$$V(a_0X+Y)=0$$

How can I continue from here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

*Hint:* In which cases do we have equality in the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality)?

> Further hint: Here, the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is used in the form $$\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)^2\le\operatorname{Var}(X) \operatorname{Var}(Y)$$

Comment: It happens for $Y = aX + b$ because:
$$Cov^2 (X,aX+b) = (E[(X-μ_X )(aX+b-E(aX+b)])^2 = (E[(X-μ_X )(aX-aμ_X ])^2=a^2 (E[(X-μ_X )^2 ])^2=a^2 (V(X))^2=V(X)V(aX+b)=V(X)V(Y)$$
But what makes it the only option?

Comment: @Netanel From the Wikipedia article on the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: „ Moreover, the two sides are equal if and only if [the two vectors] are linearly dependent“ In our case this means that we have equality if and only if $$X-\operatorname E (X)=c\cdot (Y-\operatorname{E}(Y))$$ for some constant $c$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Need more clarification on the connection between the vector version of the inequality and the probability version if that's not a trouble

Comment: @Netanel Sure, in the general case, we have an inner product space $(V,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$. In our case, we use $$V=\{\text{All square integrable random variables}\}=L^2(\Omega,\mathsf P)$$ and the inner product $$\langle f,g\rangle =\int_\Omega f(\omega)\cdot g(\omega)\,\mathrm d\mathsf P(\omega)=\mathsf E(f\cdot g)$$ For further reading see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/L2-Space.html Notice that we have $$\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=\langle X-\mathsf E(X),Y-\mathsf E(Y)$$

Comment: @Netanel About my notation: $\mathsf P$ is the probability measure, $\Omega$ is the set of events, and I forgot the closing angle in the last line

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly different proof. Let $X':=X/\sigma_X$ and $Y':=Y/\sigma_Y$. Then
\begin{align}
&\operatorname{Var}(X'+Y')=2(1+\rho_{X,Y}) \quad\text{and} \\
&\operatorname{Var}(X'-Y')=2(1-\rho_{X,Y}).
\end{align}
If $\rho_{X,Y}=1$, then $\operatorname{Var}(X'-Y')=0 \Leftrightarrow X'-Y'=\mathsf{E}X'-\mathsf{E}Y'$ a.s., which implies that
$$
Y=aX+\left(\mathsf{E}Y-a\mathsf{E}X\right) \quad\text{a.s.},
$$
where $a\equiv\sigma_Y/\sigma_X$. Similarly, when $\rho_{X,Y}=-1$,
$$
Y=-aX+\left(\mathsf{E}Y+a\mathsf{E}X\right) \quad\text{a.s.}
$$

Comment: Why does $\operatorname{Var}(X'-Y')=0 \Leftrightarrow X'-Y'=\mathsf{E}X'-\mathsf{E}Y'$ a.s.?

Comment: (1) $\operatorname{Var}(X'-Y')=\mathsf{E}[X'-Y'-\mathsf{E}X'-\mathsf{E}Y']^2$; (2) see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/897876/a-nonnegative-random-variable-has-zero-expectation-if-and-only-if-it-is-zero-alm).

Comment: Isn't that only for a non-negative variable?

Comment: @Netanel Yes. The expectation of a nonnegative r.v. is zero iff it is zero a.s.

Comment: But what if $X' \pm Y'$ is negative?

Comment: "The expectation of a nonnegative r.v. is zero iff it is zero a.s", but in your proof X and Y aren't necessarily nonnegative. How is the proof valid for any X, Y even negative?

Comment: You should look at $[(X'-\mathsf{E}X')\pm(Y'-\mathsf{E}Y')]^2$, which is nonnegative.

Comment: got it, thanks!